# Mac OSX Terminal Auto Scrolling

Tags: macos

I use mac osx terminal a lot. Whenever I want to print something more than one page onto the terminal screen, the screen stops scrolling after printing exactly one page, and shows "--More--" at the bottom of the screen to let me press "enter" to continue printing more lines, one line at a press.

What I want is the terminal screen auto scrolling to bottom of the outputs. Does anyone know how to make it?

Thank you guys for the replies. Let me illustrate with an example. After I double press tab button in my home directory, it doesn't show all the possibility of commands, which it should do, but displays a "--More--" at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: So.  This command that you run, whenever you want to print something.  Is it the [`more`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/more.1.html) command, by any chance?

Comment: It doesn't seem that "more" command is what I want. I added a example in my original post. Btw, it shows "HELP -- Press RETURN for more, or q when done" at the bottle after I type "more --help".

Answer (score 0):

Without an example, I have to imagine you're using some utility to display the file.  If you simply `cat` the file, it will show the entire contents of the file to console.  Then you're only limited by the amount of scrollback in your terminal window.

(BTW, you can change the scrollback buffer to *unlimited* in Terminal -> Preferences)

HTH

Comment: Yes, cat can show all the file. My problem is now specified in my origin post. Can we do anything about it?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about now.  I was unaware of this functionality.  But to get what you're asking for, try **`compgen -ca`** from the command line and you'll get all commands in a single column format.  GL.

Answer (score 0):

The pager that displays `--More--` is shown by readline, and it shouldn't be shown for all output but just for things like possible completions.

To remove it, add this line to `~/.inputrc`:

```
set page-completions off
```

To also remove the `Display all ... possibilities? (y or n)` prompt, add:

```
set completion-query-items 0
```